# Complex concept description in OWL

Tags: owl, protege

I’m investigating OWL, but still cannot understand the following. Let’s say we have Family class. It has BadFamily and GoodFamily subclasses (these can be also just individuals - not subclasses). In real world family concept implicates existance of several objects (Father, Mother, Son, Daughter as example). Some people in the family can love each other or hate each other (“love” and “hate” are relations as far as I understand). Accordingly in BadFamily several people hate each other. In GoodFamily several people love each other. So how can that be represented in OWL (Protege example or at lists basic direction advices would be great!).

It can be also considered as different cases description, where the same classes and relations are used for all cases, but in different combinations.

Comment: Your definitions of `GoodFamily` and `BadFamily` need clarification. It could be that if some love each other it is good, if some hate each other it is bad, but how a family with members linked with both types of properties should be classified, or the one with no such properties between members?

Comment: The thing is I mean not class recognition task. Let it be not GoodFamily or BadFamily, let that be just Family1, Family2 ... FamilyN. The main questions is - how to save cases info?

Comment: The question is even less clear now. Let's stick for a moment with a Good/Bad Family case. You could have the Family with subclasses GoodFamily and BadFamily, and you also would probably need a class FamilyMember.  Then you define the conditions for classification. Then you have individuals like Family1, Family2, Family3 and persons Person1, Person2, etc. Persons would either be asserted as family members or this could be inferred through reasoning. Then the distribution of family individuals would depend on the definition of the two sub-classes (via anonymous equivalent- or sub-classes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to implement it. You can create the following taxonomy:

-Family

--GoodFamily

--BadFamilly

-FamilyMember

--LovesFamilyMember

and for object properties:

-hasFamilyMember

-hasRelative

-lovesFamilyMember

-hatesFamilyMember

of which the latter should be declared irreflexive, to exclude classifying a family as good when the members only love themselves.

Then you need to define the class of those who love a `FamilyMember` as equivalent of `lovesFamilyMember some FamilyMember`, and the class of `GoodFamily' as equivalent of`hasFamilyMember some LovesFamilyMember`.

You need to additionally take care the respected loved and hated member is of the same family. This you can do by first defining that `hasRelative` is a object property linking a family member with a member from the same family:
`inverse (hasFamilyMember) o hasFamilyMember`. Then you need to add this relation as another condition for membership of the class `LovesFamilyMember`. Now the full definition of that class will become:
`lovesFamilyMember some FamilyMember and hasRelative some FamilyMember`.

And this is how this all looks in Turtle, together with individuals `A`, `B`, and `Family1`:

```
    #################################################################
    #    Object Properties
    #################################################################

    :hasFamilyMember rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
                     rdfs:domain :Family ;
                     rdfs:range :FamilyMember .

    :hates rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ,
                    owl:IrreflexiveProperty .

    :hatesFamilyMember rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
                       rdfs:subPropertyOf :hates ;
                       rdfs:range :FamilyMember .

    :loves rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ,
                    owl:IrreflexiveProperty .


    :lovesFamilyMember rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
                       rdfs:subPropertyOf :loves ;
                       rdfs:range :FamilyMember .

    #################################################################
    #    Classes
    #################################################################

    :BadFamily rdf:type owl:Class ;
               rdfs:subClassOf :Family .

    :Family rdf:type owl:Class .

    :FamilyMember rdf:type owl:Class .

    :GoodFamily rdf:type owl:Class ;
                owl:equivalentClass [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                      owl:onProperty :hasFamilyMember ;
                                      owl:someValuesFrom :LovesFamilyMember
                                    ] ;
                rdfs:subClassOf :Family .

:LovesFamilyMember rdf:type owl:Class ;
                   owl:equivalentClass [ owl:intersectionOf ( [ rdf:type                           owl:Restriction ;
owl:onProperty :hasRelative ;
                                                                owl:someValuesFrom :FamilyMember
                                                              ]
                                                              [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
owl:onProperty :lovesFamilyMember ;
                                                                owl:someValuesFrom :FamilyMember
                                                              ]
                                                            ) ;
                                         rdf:type owl:Class
                                       ] ;
                   rdfs:subClassOf :FamilyMember .

    #################################################################
    #    Individuals
    #################################################################

    :A rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                :FamilyMember ;
       :lovesFamilyMember :B .

    :B rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                :FamilyMember .

    :Family1 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                      :Family ;
             :hasFamilyMember :A ,
                              :B .

    :Family2 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                      :Family .

    #################################################################
    #    General axioms
    #################################################################

    [ rdf:type owl:AllDifferent ;
      owl:distinctMembers ( :A
                            :B
                          )
    ] .
```

Comment: Thank you for really detailed reply. Now I just see that the thing is that its much more simple to express knowledge in neo4j, because that all stuff with individuals and classes makes the task really complicated